Calling NSApplication from Rust using objc
I am trying to learn by doing a project of allowing AppKit certain functions , related with App and Window creation to be called from Rust using objc.
extern crate objc;
use objc::runtime::{Class,Object};
use objc::{msg_send, sel, sel_impl};

pub fn create_app(){
    unsafe {
        let app_class =Class::get("NSApplication").unwrap();
        let app:&Object = msg_send![app_class,sharedApplication];
        let _:&Object = msg_send![app_class,run];
    }
}


However if i try to run this an main.rs I get the following:
thread 'main' panicked at src/lib.rs:7:52:
called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value

I guess the objective-c is unable to find the NSApplication Class of AppKit but why and how can i resolve such an issue?
I am running all of this from a M3 MacOs just to give insight on my machine.

Note that extern crate is redundant in modern versions of Rust.

Did not know that , thanks!

Also note that objc appears abandoned, last commit 4 years ago. Maybe the author just considers it complete, but consider switching to a different crate, probably objc2.

If you use the class!() macro, does it work?

Class with name NsApplication could not be found.
Will try the objc2 maybe this one is just abandonded as you suggested.

Seems like i found the issue. It seems to work if i run it this way :
RUSTFLAGS="-C link-arg=-lobjc -C link-arg=-framework -C link-arg=AppKit" cargo run --release

If the problem is solved, either delete the question or add an Answer to it.

I dont have the full knowledge to explain as to why the below solution was correct , if anyone could explain it better you are more then welcome.
Seems like running it using the following command helps it succesfully find the AppKit classes using the objc2 crate.
RUSTFLAGS="-C link-arg=-lobjc -C link-arg=-framework -C link-arg=AppKit" cargo run --release


The Objective C runtime was not linked, which leaded to failure to find the class. It is weird, even a bug, that objc didn't forced linking it.

You can do that in a build script too.
